# Assigning a list of strings to specific values based on their substrings

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a list of returned (thus, one-of-a-kind) products that need to be assigned price values. The issue is that while there are many of the same product, they all have a different reference number. I plan to have 4 columns: Specific Products, Specific Prices, List Names, List Prices.

Check out this 3-step example of how I imagined completing this:
As you can see, the first column's entries are kind of a mess, but they contain the exact lettering as the products in the list names. The specific prices column is where I would like to put my formula in; the formula's output will be a copy of the matched product's price.

All items in the first column will be filled in randomly, but must be assigned the correct price as indicated in the 3rd and 4th columns. Because there are hundreds of products that need to be reported daily, hand-writing prices is not an option.

I would like to fill in the second column by first finding a match between the 1st and 3rd column, then assigning it the price indicated in the 4th column based on the 3rd column match. In Java, this would be a breeze, but this ain't Java. With excel, you can find a match by having the system return a boolean value with this combo:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(phrase, text)), TRUE, FALSE)
```

I've been able to string these phrases together to successfully give me what I need for these 7 products, but this is cell-specific and there are nearly a thousand products I would have to code. =LOOKUP is a near match to what I need, the only problem being that my actual product names are not verbatim to the listed product names. Any suggestions?

This isn't how it HAS to work, in fact I'd love someone to give me a fresh take on it.

[image: spreadsheet]

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/n2yiresq9/

Answer (score 0):

In Google Spreadsheets, you can enter the following in C2, and then copy down the column:

```
=array_constrain(filter(E$2:E, regexmatch(A2, D$2:D)), 1, 1)
```

This checks, for each string in D column, whether A2 contains this string, and returns the corresponding entry from E. The wrapper `array_constrain` indicates that only the first match should be returned.

Hopefully you don't have products that match multiple names in column D, or the problem becomes ambiguous.

Here is a more verbose formula that does not attempt to sweep the issue of multiple matches under the rug with array_constrain: it will throw #REF error in such cases.

```
=arrayformula(filter(filter(E$2:E, len(D$2:D)), regexmatch(A2, filter(D$2:D, len(D$2:D)))))
```

The principle is the same, except the array is no longer constrained and the empty cells in column D are filtered out -- this becomes necessary without the constraint, since empty string is contained in any other string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this in Excel.  Using an array-entered formula (formula entered by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`:

```
=INDEX(LIST_PRICE,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(PRODUCT_NAMES,A2)),0))
```

`PRODUCT_NAMES` and `LIST_PRICE` are named ranges referring to the data range in your Columns D and E in your picture.